# Why do some Unicode characters display in matrices, but not data frames in R?

Tags: r

For at least some cases, Asian characters are printable if they are contained in a `matrix`, or a `vector`, but not in a `data.frame`. Here is an example

```
q<-'天'

q # Works
# [1] "天" 

matrix(q) # Works
#      [,1]
# [1,] "天"

q2<-data.frame(q,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
q2 # Does not work
#          q
# 1 <U+5929>

q2[1,] # Works again.
# [1] "天"
```

Clearly, my device is capable of displaying the character, but when it is in a `data.frame`, it does not work.

Doing some digging, I found that the `print.data.frame` function runs `format` on each column. It turns out that if you run `format.default` directly, the same problem occurs:

```
format(q)
# "<U+5929>"
```

Digging into `format.default`, I find that it is calling the internal `format`, written in C.

Before I dig any further, I want to know if others can reproduce this behaviour. **Is there some configuration of R that would allow me to display these characters within `data.frame`s?**

My `sessionInfo()`, if it helps:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.1
```

Comment: Try setting `Sys.setlocale( locale="UTF-8" )`. It's a bit strange that rendering is inconsistent; however, `English_Canada.1252` isn't intended to handle Asian characters anyhow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but although the comments and answers helped, they weren't quite right. In Windows, it doesn't seem like you can set a generic 'UTF-8' locale. You can, however, set country-specific locales, which will work in this case:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", locale="Chinese")
q2 # Works fine
#  q
#1 天
```

But, it does make me wonder why exactly `format` seems to use the `locale`; I wonder if there is a way to have it ignore the locale in Windows. I also wonder if there is some generic `UTF-8` locale that I don't know about on Windows.

Comment: I'll leave this open for a bit before I check my own answer if someone wants to chime in with some more elaborate explanation of what is going on here.

Comment: I just fell over this, and according to Duncan Murdoch it's a bug (though a tricky one to fix). https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-May/071252.html

Comment: @RichieCotton Ah! I knew it was a bug. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: When we are done do we need to change it back or is it automatic when you restart R?

Comment: Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", locale="Persian") worked for farsi too

Answer (score 6):

I just [blogged about Unicode and R](http://fdatamining.blogspot.hk/2013/07/unicode-tips-in-python-2-and-r.html) several days ago. I think your R editor is UTF-8 and this gives your illusion that R in your Windows handles UTF-8 characters.

The short answer is when you want to process Unicode (Here, it is Chinese), don't use English Windows, use a Chinese version Windows or Linux which by default is UTF-8.

Session info in my Ubuntu:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Comment: @nograpes, In my Ubuntu and RStudio, there is no such display problem.

Comment: Interesting. Can you post your `sessionInfo()` so I can compare and contrast our configurations?

Comment: I was mistaken, I cannot reproduce the problem under Ubuntu. However, although this helps, it doesn't explain if there is a configuration of R under Windows that can resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm on CentOS 6.3 and I also can't set locale following this post. However, my `sessionInfo()` is partially unicode, partially not.