# How can I get a unicode symbol into factor levels for a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to get a symbol in a ggplot legend without specifying in the scale.

I want this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=factor(1:5, labels=c(1:4, "\u2265 5")), c=10:14)

ggplot(df, aes(a,c, color=b)) + geom_point()
```

which produces this plot

[image]

To produce a plot like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(a,c, color=b)) + geom_point() + scale_color_brewer(labels=c(1:4, "\u2265 5"))
```

[image]

Is that possible?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4   digest_0.6.4       grid_3.1.2        
 [4] gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.3       MASS_7.3-35       
 [7] munsell_0.4.2      plyr_1.8.1         proto_0.3-10      
[10] RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.11.3        reshape2_1.4      
[13] scales_0.2.4       stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: If you name factor levels of `b` as `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `≥5`, yes.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik the problem is that `≥` is being converted to `=` in the data.frame (on my Windows 7 PC). Try `labels=c(1:4, "\u2265 5");labels`.

Comment: I have tested it and it indeed doesn't work. Interesting.

Comment: Hmm, on my system `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)` data.frame as well as legend is ok.

Comment: @redmode that figures! A windows problem most likely (as per usual).

Comment: I am indeed using a windows 7 PC as well. `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)` and `ggplot2 0.9.3.1`.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Windows as well, but notably `plot(df$a,df$c,main='\u2265')` works.

Comment: Also, you can label the legend properly with Unicode: `ggplot(df, aes(a,c, color=b)) + geom_point() + scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "\u2265"))`. I suspect that this is related to a [previous question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715956/why-do-some-unicode-characters-display-in-matrices-but-not-data-frames-in-r). You'll note that the character probably doesn't display correctly when you just type `df` either.

Comment: @nograpes Explicitly putting the unicode in ggplot works for me too (whether in the legend, or titles, or axis labels). It's the passing via a factor that gets me. You're right typing `df` does not work, but typing `df$b` does.

Comment: I believe it is an instance of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448811/what-does-format-do-to-utf-8-strings.