# What does `format` do to UTF-8 strings?

Tags: r, string, utf-8

From the documentation, `format` should do the following:

> Format an R object for pretty printing.

Now how does that go along with the following example:

```
> format("\u2264")
[1] "="
```

Can anyone explain what is going on?

EDIT:

I'm using R on Windows. The problem appears in R 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5.
The problem does not appear on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

From the R [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/format) for `format`:

> [returns] An object of similar structure to x containing character representations of the elements of the first argument x in a common format, and (emphasis mine) **in the current locale's encoding**.

You may try running `Sys.getenv("LANG")` to see what your current R environment encoding is.  Assuming it be UTF-8, then seeing `≤` makes sense, as this is the UTF-8 representation of the Unicode literal `\u2264`.

Note: I get `≤` as the output for `format("\u2264")` in my R tool, which is correct as compared against the Unicode tables.  Perhaps you have a typo in your question.