# How to display a message/warning/error with Unicode characters under Windows?

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I have a message (or warning or error) containing Unicode characters.  (The string has `UTF-8` encoding.)

```
x <- "\u20AC \ub124" # a euro symbol, and Hangul 'ne'
## [1] "€ 네"
Encoding(x)
## [1] "UTF-8"
```

Under Linux, this prints OK in a message if the locale is UTF-8 (`` l10n_info()$`UTF-8` `` returns `TRUE`).

I can force this, by doing, e.g.,

```
devtools::with_locale(
  c(LC_CTYPE = "en_US.utf8"),
  message(x)  
)
## € 네
```

Under Windows there are no UTF-8 locales, so I can't find an equivalent way to enforce correct printing.  For example, with a US locale, the Hangul character doesn't display properly.

```
devtools::with_locale(
  c(LC_CTYPE = "English_United States"),
  message(x)  
)
## € <U+B124>
```

There's a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17715956/134830) with Unicode characters not displaying properly when printing data frames under Windows.  The advice there was to set the locale to Chinese/Japanese/Korean.  This does not work here.

```
devtools::with_locale(
  c(LC_CTYPE = "Korean_Korea"),
  message(x)  
)
## ¢æ ³×   # equivalent to iconv(x, "UTF-8", "EUC-KR")
```

How can I get UTF-8 messages, warnings and errors to display correctly under Windows?

Comment: Which Windows version are you referring to? I suspect that you cannot solve this problem on Windows 7, but maybe other versions finally gained proper Unicode support. (I do not hold my breath however)

Comment: @mpiktas I tested it under Windows 7, though AFAIK, R doesn't support UTF-8 locales for newer versions of Windows either, so I suspect the problem applies to all versions.  Happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: I suspect that there is something going in with printing to stderr. `message` prints to stderr and then we have a problem: compare `cat(x, file = stdout())` to `cat(x, file = stderr())`. I tried looking into R source code and I only managed to find out that printing to stdout and to stderr is done via different functions, but I lack knowledge in R internals to find where are the roots of the problem.

Comment: Also if you look into `Encoding(capture.output(print(x)))` you will see that encoding is not "UTF-8". So I can only surmise, that somewhere along encoding information gets mangled when printing to stderr.

Comment: @mpiktas Yes, the problem with `capture.output` is a bug I spotted the other day. https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16539, and I've submitted this stderr issue as another bug https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16543

Comment: There's also a bug in RStudio that causes incorrect display. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/205382758-UTF-8-strings-do-not-print-correctly-to-stderr-under-Windows

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the help for the function Sys.setlocale() in R says this: "LC_MESSAGES" will be "C" on systems that do not support message translation, *and is not supported on Windows*.

To me this sounds like modifying character representation for R messages/errors can't be done on any Windows version...