# R: Unicode characters in data frame names

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

In R for Windows I can assign a unicode character as follows:

```
(u <- "\U0444")
# [1] "ф"
```

However, assigning the string to a data frame gives an unreadable output:

```
x <- data.frame(1)
setNames(x,u)
#   <U+0444>
# 1        1
```

*Session Info*

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Comment: Looks like it's just the way R prints the `data.frame`. If you try `colnames(x) = u;colnames(x)` you should see the correct symbol.

Comment: @MikeH.: well, even if it were so, it would not be the _proper way to  print._  However, it works on Ubuntu and on Windows too if you switch to the similar `\U0424`.
Beside  `colanames(x)`, `names(x)` prints properly too, but this question is about printing a whole data frame.

Comment: Interestingly, if it's a matrix it works: `as.matrix(x)`. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715956/why-do-some-unicode-characters-display-in-matrices-but-not-data-frames-in-r