# Unicode in column names

Tags: r, unicode

Just like in title, I'd like to put some Unicode characters to column names of data frame.

Toy example:

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:3, y=4:6)
 
(nm<-c('x\u00b2', 'y\u2082'))
"x²" "y₂"
 
colnames(df)<-nm
 
df
  x2 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
```

As you can see, sub- and supercripts are converted to "ordinary" digits.

One more try:

```
 (nm<-c('x\u03B2', 'y\u2082'))
 "xβ" "y₂"
 
 colnames(df)<-nm
 
 df
  xß y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
```

Now greek β is converted to german ß (despite my Windows locale is Poland...)

Finally, greek gamma seems to be left as it is:

```
 (nm<-c('x\u03B3', 'y\u2082'))
 "xγ" "y₂"
 
 colnames(df)<-nm
 
 df
  x<U+03B3> y2
1         1  4
2         2  5
3         3  6
Warning message:
In do.call(data.frame, c(x, alis)) :
  unable to translate 'x<U+03B3>' to native encoding
```

So, in general: is there a way to avoid converting Unicode characters to their "nearest neigbours"?

**EDIT**

I know that calling `colnames(df)` gives appropriate results:

```
    (nm<-c('x\u00b2', 'y\u2082'))
    "x²" "y₂"
     
    colnames(df)<-nm

    colnames(df)
    "x²" "y₂"
```

My goal is to get them from simple `df` or `print(df)` call.

Comment: Those are escape sequences, not Unicode. This page is Unicode which is why I can write  Αυτό Εδώ και Γ, γ, Σ, ω, Ω, β, Ψ knowing it will appear without problem, without any escape sequences or contacting SO support to have them change the way they store text

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023570/r-unicode-characters-in-data-frame-names

Comment: `are converted to "ordinary" digits` how do you display the characters? Are you sure the problem isn't your terminal or IDE? Or perhaps you need to explicitly set your environment on Linux or Mac to  use UTF8?  How is your environment set, eg the `LC_ALL`  env variable? What OS, terminal, IDE are you using? If you use Mac, you may have to modify *two* profiles for the change to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the characters to stick by bypassing `colnames<-`:

```
attr(df,"names") <- nm
print(df)
  xβ y₂
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6

colnames(df)
[1] "xβ" "y₂"
```

Use at your own risk.

```
sessionInfo()
#R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
#
#Matrix products: default
#BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecL#ib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
#LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#
#locale:
#[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Really sorry, but this works exactly like `colnames<-`. `colnames(df)` preserves `\uxxxx` sequences while simple `df` call does not.

Comment: Last command in your answer is `colnames(df)` and it works fine. But if you instead call just `df` you end up with `xß` and `y2`. The same is when you assign colnames with `colnames(df)<-nm`. See my edit.

Comment: Can you add a result of calling `print(df)` or simply `df` to your answer?

Comment: OK, I see. So I'll try to play with locale settings. Thank you!

Comment: Don't feel obligated to accept the answer if it doesn't solve your problem. Instead, maybe edit with your `sessionInfo()` like I show in my answer.

Comment: I changed locale and your solution worked :)