# Displaying the contents in local language : R

Tags: html, r, xml, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to download the data from the website that contains the contents in both English and local language (non-English). I was able to get the data that were in English, but for the contents that were in the local language, I got something like below. My question is how do I display both?

```
X1  X2  X3
NA      
1   <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
2   <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
3   <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
4   <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
5   <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
6   <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
7   <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
8   <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
9   <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
10  <U+0926><U+094B><U+0932><U+0916><U+093E>    <U+0915><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0928><U+094D><U+091A><U+094B><U+0915>  <U+0917><U+093E><U+0909><U+0901><U+092A><U+093E><U+0932><U+093F><U+0915><U+093E>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have the text that you want, It simply is being displayed incorrectly.

I can reproduce your problem. Your example data had the same strings 10 times. 
To keep the display reasonable,  I am only repeating 3 times.

```
## Hex codes from your example
S1 = c("0926", "094B", "0932", "0916", "093E") 
S2 = c("0915", "093E", "0932", "093F", "0928", "094D", "091A", "094B", "0915")  
S3 = c("0917", "093E", "0909", "0901", "092A", "093E", "0932", "093F", "0915", "093E")

## Convert to Devanagari strings
X1 = rep(intToUtf8(strtoi(S1, base=16L)), 3)
X2 = rep(intToUtf8(strtoi(S2, base=16L)), 3)
X3 = rep(intToUtf8(strtoi(S3, base=16L)), 3)

df = data.frame(X1, X2, X3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now `X1` will display correctly, but `df` will not

Bizarrely, `df$X1` and `df[,1]` will display the unicode, 
but `df[1, ]`  will not.

A workaround is that `as.matrix(df)` will display the whole thing
as unicode characters.

This is apparently a known bug in the Windows version of the RGui.
Some other explorations of this can be found at this 
[Earlier SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17715956/4752675) 
and this [Mailing List Post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-May/071252.html)

**Addendum**

Writing these strings to a readable Unicode file requires some care. 
This created a csv file for my example.

```
Mat = as.matrix(df)
F <- file("Test1.csv", "wb", encoding="UTF-8")
BOM <- charToRaw('\xEF\xBB\xBF')
writeBin(BOM, F)
for(r in 1:nrow(Mat)) {
    Line = paste(Mat[r,], collapse=",")
    writeLines(Line, F, useBytes=T) 
}
close(F)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Any idea how to save the matrix so that I can view characters not only in console but also in the saved file (e.g., csv)?

Comment: Too complicated for comment. Adding to answer.