# R failing to preserve some special characters

Tags: r, unicode

I have recently updated to R-4.0.3 and am having trouble running some of my old code.

Some unicode characters seem to be "simplified" by R to the point that they change their meaning or are meaningless.

`c("a ≥ b", "√2", "360°")` returns
`[1] "a = b" "v2"    "360°"`

I can correctly render the symbols using their unicode codepoint, but when I do anything to the resulting character vector the special characters are not preserved.

```
char_str <- c("a \u2265 b", "\u221A2", "360\u00B0")

> char_str
[1] "a ≥ b" "√2"    "360°"

> data.frame(char_str)
  char_str
1    a = b
2       v2
3     360°
```

In previous installation of R (3.xx) the ≥ and √ were preserved when put into a data.frame. I am eventually passing a data frame to a `flextable::` object to put into a .docx using `officer::`. I would settle for a solution that never renders the chars until the final step.

Comment: What does your `locale()` show?

Comment: I can reproduce your problem on R 4.0.2. I wonder if the issue is with `print.data.frame`, if I do `d = data.frame(x = "a \u2265 b")`, `print(dd)` shows `=`, but `print(dd[[1]])` shows `≥`. So the information is still there, it's just not being printed correctly. I have a cloud machine up running 3.6.2, and it also reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hmmm, doing some more googling, this might be known issue with Windows. See [this old Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17715956/903061), and [this thread on r-devel](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Unicode-display-problem-with-data-frames-under-Windows-td4707639.html). The good news is it should be fine when you put it into a .docx.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on R 4.0.3 on Mac. It works the same for me if either in data.frame or vector.