# Tibetan characters in data.frames cannot be displayed in R console even after locale is set (Chinese is fine, Tibetan in matrices is fine)

Tags: r, encoding, locale

In R, Tibetan characters do not display properly when they are located in data.frames:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Tibetan")
[1] "Tibetan_China.950"
> data.frame(a="བོད་")
                                 a
1 <U+0F56><U+0F7C><U+0F51><U+0F0B>
> Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Dzongkha_Bhutan.950")
[1] "Dzongkha_Bhutan.950"
> data.frame(a="འབྲུག་ཡུལ་")
                                                                                 a
1 <U+0F60><U+0F56><U+0FB2><U+0F74><U+0F42><U+0F0B><U+0F61><U+0F74><U+0F63><U+0F0B>
```

Chinese is fine following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715956/why-do-some-unicode-characters-display-in-matrices-but-not-data-frames-in-r):

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Chinese")
[1] "Chinese (Simplified)_China.936"
> data.frame(a="中文")
     a
1 中文
```

Tibetan characters are also fine in matrices:

```
> matrix("བོད")
     [,1]
[1,] "བོད"
```

Could anyone shed some light on this issue? I'm using Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty curious about this issue; why do some languages (like Tibetan) work differently in R for Windows than others (like Chinese). It's not just in data frames, you get the same problem with `enc2native`. For example, set locale to Chinese and then `enc2native("\u4e2d\u6587")` will print the string to the console as Chinese characters. But set locale to Tibetan and `enc2native("\u0f56\u0f7c\u0f51\u0f0b")` does not give Tibetan characters. Have a look at Ista Zahn's article here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/06/escaping-from-character-encoding-hell-in-r-on-windows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in R 4.2.0:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "Tibetan")
[1] "Tibetan_China.utf8"
> 
> data.frame(a="བོད་")
    a
1 བོད་
```

Not a satisfactory answer at the time I posted this, but certainly works well now!