# how to read data in utf-8 format in R?

Tags: r, utf-8

My system:win7+R-3.0.2.

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_CTYPE=Chinese 
(Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's        
republic of China.936;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936"
```

There are two files with same content saved in microsoft notepad: [one](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1c0pGvqK) is saved as ansi format, [the other](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1kT7IYft) is saved as utf8 format.The data is death name in M370  Malaysia Airlines .
Or you can create the file this way.

1)copy the data into microsoft notepad.

```
乘客姓名,性别,出生日期
HuangTianhui,男,1948/05/28
姜翠云,女,1952/03/27
李红晶,女,1994/12/09
```

2)save it as  test.ansi with ansi format in notepad.
3)save it as  test.utf8 with utf-8 format in notepad.

```
read.table("test.ansi",sep=",",header=TRUE)  #can work fine
read.table("test.utf8",sep=",",header=TRUE)  #can't work
```

Then, i set encoding into utf-8.

```
options(encoding="utf-8")
read.table("test.utf8",sep=",",header=TRUE,encoding="utf-8")


 In read.table("test.utf8", sep = ",",header=TRUE,encoding = "utf-8") :
invalid input found on input connection 'test.utf8'
```

How can I read the data file (test.utf8)?
In python,it is so simple

```
rfile=open("g:\\test.utf8","r",encoding="utf-8").read()
rfile
'\ufeff乘客姓名,性别,出生日期\n\nHuangTianhui,男,1948/05/28\n\n姜翠云,女,1952/03
/27\n\n李红晶,女,1994/12/09'
rfile.replace("\n\n","\n").replace("\ufeff","").splitlines()
['乘客姓名,性别,出生日期', 'HuangTianhui,男,1948/05/28', '姜翠云,女,1952/03/27',
 '李红晶,女,1994/12/09']
```

Python can do such job better than R.

I do as Sathish say, problem solved a little ,still remain some.
I found that when the data is in data.frame ,it can not be displayed properly,
when the data is a column of data.frame ,it can be displayed properly,
strange enough,when the data is a row of data.frame,it can not be displayed properly .

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's best if you provide a minimal, reproducible example here, rather than linking offsite. I tried to get your UTF-8 data, but quickly got bored by the popups and speed of the website you sent me to.

Comment: What is Microsoft Agenda? Do you mean Excel?

Comment: Try with uppercase for the encoding string: `read.table("test.utf8", sep=",", header=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: %windir%\system32\notepad.exe

Comment: question remain,it make me feel that there must be a bug in encoding of R ,please see my edited text,the hole become more deeper as you explore .

Comment: no,I found that when the data is in data.frame ,it can not be displayed properly,
when the data is a column of data.frame ,it can be displayed properly,
strange enough,when the data is a row of data.frame,it can not be displayed properly .that is my new discover.

Comment: solved,i think R should be improved to solve such encoding problem,in python it is simple.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OS: Windows-7 (64-bit)

R Version:

```
package_version(R.version)

[1] ‘3.0.2’
```

Change your locale from "chinese" to "English_United States.1252"

```
  Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")

  Sys.getlocale(category="LC_ALL")

[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United        States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

Read in data with chinese encoding

```
 df_ch <- read.table("test.utf8",
                     sep=",",
                     header=FALSE, 
                     encoding="chinese", 
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE
                    )
```

Read in data with UTF-8 encoding

```
 df_utf8 <- read.table("test.utf8",
                        sep=",",
                        header=FALSE, 
                        encoding="UTF-8", 
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE 
                      )
```

## In RStudio Version 0.98.501

```
 df_ch$V1[1]

[1] "ï»¿ä¹˜å®¢å§“å"

 df_utf8$V1[1]

[2] "乘客姓名"

 df_utf8$V1

[1] "乘客姓名"         "HuangTianhui"    "姜翠云"          "李红晶"          "LuiChing"        "宋飞飞"         
[7] "唐旭东"          "YangJiabao"      "买买提江·阿布拉" "安文兰"          "鲍媛华"          "边亮京"         
[13] "边茂勤"          "曹蕊"            "车俊章"          "陈长军"          "陈建设"          "陈昀"           
[19] "戴淑玲"          "丁立军"          "丁莹"            "丁颖"            "董国伟"          "杜文忠"         
[25] "冯栋"            "冯纪新"          "付宝峰"          "甘福祥"          "甘涛"            "高歌"           
[31] "管文杰"          "韩静"            "侯爱琴"          "侯波"            "胡偲婠(婴儿)"    "胡效宁"
```

Display unicode data for a row from a data frame

```
  df_utf8[1,]
                                    V1               V2                               V3
  1 <U+FEFF><U+4E58><U+5BA2><U+59D3><U+540D> <U+6027><U+522B> <U+51FA><U+751F><U+65E5><U+671F>
```

Display chinese data for a row from a data frame

```
as.character(df_utf8[1,])

[1] "乘客姓名"  "性别"     "出生日期"

as.character(df_utf8[2,])

[1] "HuangTianhui" "男"           "1948/05/28"
```

Displaying multiple columns of data with international characters can be performed by converting the data frame into list and by forcing the data into character format.

```
  df_utf8_ch <- lapply(df_utf8, as.character)

  df_utf8_ch
```

$V1
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPgGX.jpg) "乘客姓名"         "HuangTianhui"    "姜翠云"          "李红晶"          "LuiChing"        "宋飞飞"
 [7](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html) "唐旭东"          "YangJiabao"      "买买提江·阿布拉" "安文兰"          "鲍媛华"          "边亮京"
 [13] "边茂勤"          "曹蕊"            "车俊章"          "陈长军"          "陈建设"          "陈昀"
 [19] "戴淑玲"          "丁立军"          "丁莹"            "丁颖"            "董国伟"          "杜文忠"
 [25] "冯栋"            "冯纪新"          "付宝峰"          "甘福祥"          "甘涛"            "高歌"
 [31] "管文杰"          "韩静"            "侯爱琴"          "侯波"            "胡偲婠(婴儿)"    "胡效宁"
 [37] "黄毅"            "姜学仁"          "姜颖"            "焦微微"          "焦文学"          "鞠坤"
 [43] "康旭"            "黎明中"          "李国辉"          "李洁"            "李乐"            "李文博"
 [49] "李燕"            "李宇辰"          "李志锦"          "李志欣"          "李智"            "栗延林"
 [55] "梁路阳"          "梁旭阳"          "林安南"          "林明峰"          "刘凤英"          "刘金鹏"
 [61] "刘强"            "刘如生"          "刘顺超"          "柳忠福"          "楼宝棠"          "卢先初"
 [67] "鹿建华"          "罗伟"            "马骏"            "马文芝"          "毛土贵"          "么立飞"
 [73] "蒙高生"          "孟兵"            "孟凡余"          "欧阳欣"          "石贤文"          "宋春玲"
 [79] "宋坤"            "苏强国"          "汤雪竹"          "田军伟"          "田清君"          "汪厚彬"
 [85] "王春勇"          "王纯华"          "王丹"            "王海涛"          "王利军"          "王林诗"
 [91] "王墨恒(婴儿)"    "王守宪"          "王淑敏"          "王献军"          "王永刚"

$V2
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPgGX.jpg) "性别" "男"   "女"   "女"   "女"   "男"   "男"   "女"   "男"   "女"   "女"   "男"   "女"   "女"   "女"   "男"
 [17] "男"   "女"   "女"   "男"   "女"   "女"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "女"   "男"   "女"
 [33] "女"   "男"   "女"   "男"   "女"   "男"   "女"   "女"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "女"   "男"   "女"
 [49] "女"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "女"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"
 [65] "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "女"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "男"   "女"   "男"
$V3
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPgGX.jpg) "出生日期"   "1948/05/28" "1952/03/27" "1994/12/09" "1969/08/02" "1982/03/01" "1983/08/03" "1988/08/25"
  [9] "1979/07/10" "1949/10/20" "1951/10/21" "1987/06/06" "1947/07/19" "1982/02/19" "1946/03/20" "1979/06/06"
 [17] "1956/03/07" "1957/08/11" "1956/12/07" "1971/04/06" "1952/04/25" "1986/10/24" "1966/10/26" "1964/06/07"
 [25] "1993/03/09" "1944/01/06" "1986/12/06" "1965/11/21" "1970/01/29" "1987/11/16" "1979/10/03" "1961/05/28"
 [33] "1969/06/24" "1979/05/15" "2011/02/25" "1980/01/01" "1984/06/18" "有待确认"   "1987/04/13" "1983/05/09"
 [41] "1956/12/17" "1982/11/07" "1980/08/09" "1945/12/19" "1958/05/18" "1987/02/06" "1982/12/03" "1985/07/16"
 [49] "1983/07/19" "1987/11/06" "1984/04/14" "1979/05/22" "1973/05/05" "1985/10/26" "1954/03/26" "1984/11/12"
 [57] "1987/03/27" "1980/05/25" "1949/05/10" "1981/12/26" "1974/08/13" "1938/01/22" "1968/02/29" "1942/05/22"
 [65] "1935/04/21" "1981/10/14" "1957/03/28" "1985/08/20" "1981/12/25" "1957/08/01" "1942/08/02" "1983/06/15"
 [73] "1950/01/01" "1974/04/26" "1944/08/23" "1976/10/12" "1988/01/18" "1954/04/06"

```
 View(df_ch)
```

[image: chinese encoding]

```
 View(df_utf8)
```

[image]

## In RGui (64-bit)

[image]

View(df_ch)

[image]

View(df_utf8)

[image]

The good thing is you have all data in utf8 format to be used for further data analysis.

Once your analysis is done, you may change the locale back to "chinese"

```
  Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "chinese")

  Sys.getlocale(category="LC_ALL")

 [1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_CTYPE=Chinese   (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936"
```

Some functions you may need to explore for converting between character string encodings.

[Encoding()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html)

[iconv()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html)

HTH

Comment: `乘客姓名,性别,出生日期
HuangTianhui,男,1948/05/28
姜翠云,女,1952/03/27
李红晶,女,1994/12/09`  will be read as `  ï..ä¹.å..å..å.. æ..å.. å.ºç.Ÿæ..æœŸ
1    HuangTianhui    ç”·   1948/05/28
2       å§œç¿ äº‘    å¥³   1952/03/27
3       æŽçº¢æ™¶    å¥³   1994/12/09
` old problem become a new one,there is no such thing in python.

Comment: problem remain,in my system:

Answer (score 2):

Try a different argument for read.table: `fileEncoding`:

```
 read.table("test.utf8", sep = "," , header=TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: i tried it ,can't work.maybe there is something related my locale,my locale is ` "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_CTYPE=Chinese 
(Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's        
republic of China.936;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936"`,if you already opened it,what is your locale? how can i change it into yours?