# Importing data with Vietnamese characters into R

Tags: xml, r, unicode

Please can someone suggest the best way to import data with Vietnamese characters into an R dataframe, so that the data are depicted correctly. The kind of data I need to import includes a longer version of the column below:

```
Student_name

PHẠM THANH

PHẠM VĂN

NGUYỄN TUẤN

NGUYỄN VĂN

VŨ NGỌC
```

I tried many options including saving the data as Unicode.txt and importing into R with `encoding = UTF-8` specified.

With `read.csv` or `read.table`, I get the error message

> In `read.table("Stu.txt", header = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")` :
>     line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls

Saving as an MS-Excel file and importing with `read.xlsx` (package `xlsx`), I can read the data alright, without specifying encoding I get weird output, as shown:

```
 Student_name
```

1    PHáº M THANH

2     PHáº M VÄ‚N

3 NGUYá»„N TUáº¤N

4   NGUYá»„N VÄ‚N

5   NGUYá»„N VÄ‚N

6      VÅ¨ NGá»ŒC

With `read.xlsx`, and `encoding="UTF-8"`, I get the UTF-8 translation alright, but without hex codes, so the output has the names enclosed in less than and
greater than signs PH <'U+1EA0'>M THANH and so on, without the quotation marks.

I am running R through RStudio,Version 0.99.467, with Windows 7 operating system.

Thank you.

Comment: So you are saying that your .xlsx file is XML, which is usually implictly UTF8 coded without a BOM and that you looked inside the .xlsx and you know what XML charset is specified?  Are you saying your problem is an R problem, or your problem is an Excel problem?  You should say exactly what is in the xlsx file and what leads you to believe you have an R problem.

Comment: The .xlsx file is a default .xlsx. I also saved the column separately as a Unicode .txt file, and as a .csv file This file I can open in Notepad or MS-Excel with the correct depiction of characters. I can even copy and paste the column into my RStudio script window and read with textConnection, but the problem persists, so is surely a problem with commands I need to give to R to decode the characters adequately.

Comment: Do you understand what I said? Do you know how to examine a file and determine it's actual encoding?

Comment: Please see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876746/how-to-read-data-in-utf-8-format-in-r

Comment: I am afraid I did not understand what you said and your question either. Perhaps the example below will explain.library(data.table)
toread <- "PHẠM THANH
PHẠM VĂN
NGUYỄN TUẤN
NGUYỄN VĂN
NGUYỄN VĂN
VŨ NGỌC"

Comment: Thanks, I did read the question 22876746 on Chinese characters, but it did not help. I don't understand @Warrenp 's question about the file either, because if I try to read the data inside the script, with DT <- read.table(textConnection(toread),header=FALSE,encoding="UTF-8"), the name PHẠM reads as PH<U+1EA0>M.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `stri_trans_general` function from the stringi package:

```
data <- read.table("Stu.txt", header = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")  %>% 
         mutate(Student_name = stri_trans_general(Student_name, "Latin-ASCII"))
```