# Define encoding in R script?

Tags: r, character-encoding

Is it possible to define encoding in R script?

Something like that (just example):

```
encoding("utf-8")
```

I know for Reopen with encoding in RStudio, but I am not looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
## x is intended to be in latin1
x <- "fa\xE7ile"
Encoding(x)
Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
x
xx <- iconv(x, "latin1", "UTF-8")
Encoding(c(x, xx))
c(x, xx)
Encoding(xx) <- "bytes"
xx # will be encoded in hex
cat("xx = ", xx, "\n", sep = "")
```

http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Encoding

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html

[how to read data in utf-8 format in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876746/how-to-read-data-in-utf-8-format-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to write another script that has the following code:

`source('C:/Script.R', encoding = 'UTF-8')`

replace "C:/Script.R" with your script path & name.

Then when you call this script, it will run 'Script.R' with UTF-8 encoding.