# R H2O package import csv file with Chinese characters

Tags: r, h2o

I have a large dataset in `csv` format to build a prediction model. Because of its size, I planned to use `h2o` package in *R* to build the model. However, the data, in multiple columns of the `data.frame`, contains some Chinese Simplified characters and `h2o` is having difficulty receiving the data.

I've tried two different approaches. The first approach involved directly reading from the file using the `h2o.importFile()` function to import the data. However, this approach ends up converting the Chinese characters into some messy codes.

The second approach I've tried to first bring the data into *R* using `readr` and base R `read_csv`/`read.csv` functions. After the data is loaded correctly into *R*, I tried to convert the `data.frame` into `h2o` frame using `as.h2o` function. Though, the end result of this approach also resulted in a messed up translation.

To illustrate, I've written the following piece of codes as an example:

```
require(h2o)
dat<-data.frame(x=rep(c("北京","上海"),50),
                y=rnorm(mean=10,sd=3,n=100))
h2o.init(nthreads=-1)
h2o.dat<-as.h2o(dat)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would consider this a bug since R's data.frame can display the characters, but at the same time, the R H2OFrame cannot.  I checked that this works for H2OFrames in Python, so it's an R issue only.  I filed a bug [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3893).

**Update:** This has been fixed (I have checked that it's working in H2O 3.32.0.1, but it was probably fixed a while ago).

Comment: Are there any developments on this issue?

Comment: @wake_wake This has been fixed (see update above).

Comment: Interesting! It still doesn't work on my Windows machine. Even if I set `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Chinese")` I get weird characters when I transform my correct characters from a `as.character` to a `as.h2o`. I end up with text like this:  "氓鈥犈撁︼拷鈥<98>"

Comment: @wake_wake What version of H2O are you using and which version of Windows?

Comment: I am using H2O 3.33.0.5287 on Microsoft R Open 4.0.2 and Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Thanks @wake_wake, we re-opened the ticket to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if it is the best way but I have worked on Korean data before and this the process I generally follow. 
First, ensure that the data you need to read is encoded as "UTF-8". 
Second, ensure that the locale is set to English

```
Sys.getlocale(category="LC_ALL")
```

You can then read the file using the below statement,

```
dat <- read.csv("Test.txt",header=T,encoding = "UTF-8",stringsAsFactors = F)

dat[,1]
[1] "北京" "上海" "北京" "上海"

dat
        X.U.FEFF.X Y
1 <U+5317><U+4EAC> 1
2 <U+4E0A><U+6D77> 2
3 <U+5317><U+4EAC> 3
4 <U+4E0A><U+6D77> 4
```

As you can see, when you view the entire data.frame you see them as "UTF-8" encodes but you can also look at the chinese characters by looking using `df[1,]` and looking at each vector.

Comment: Hi @ab90hi, thanks for your advice. Actually, I had no problem in reading the original dataset into R and show them as appropriate Chinese characters by using read_csv from dplyr. The challenge is to import or transform the original data set into an H2OFrame and show them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is only related with R not showing encoded character inside H2O frames however the data inside h2o frames is still totally preserved as in original frame. Once you use H2O Web/FLOW UI and see the h2o frame you will see data inside h2o frame is exactly same as original frame. The following image shows results at various location i.e RStudio, R view window and in H2O FLOW UI

[image]

Please following the link below for a solution however you must be able to update locals in your machine to view those characters in the H2O data frames:

[how to read data in utf-8 format in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876746/how-to-read-data-in-utf-8-format-in-r)