# readr::read_csv issue: Chinese Character becomes messy codes

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, readr

I'm trying to import a dataset to RStudio, however I am stuck with Chinese characters, as they become messy codes. Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_csv("中文,英文\n英文,德文")
df
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4`            `Ӣ\xce\xc4`
               <chr>                  <chr>
1 "<U+04E2>\xce\xc4" "<U+00B5>\xc2\xce\xc4"
```

When I use the base function read.csv, it works well. I guess I must do something wrong with encoding. But there are no encoding option in read_csv, how can I do this?

Comment: You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876746/how-to-read-data-in-utf-8-format-in-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577764/set-locale-to.-system-default-utf-8).  In `read_csv`, there is a `locale` argument.  According to documentation `locale 
The locale controls defaults that vary from place to place. The default locale is US-centric (like R), but you can use locale() to create your own locale that controls things like the default time zone, encoding, decimal mark, big mark, and day/month names`.

Comment: Also note, `readr` can read alternate encodings via `locale`. However, *all readr functions yield strings encoded in UTF-8* according to [package documentation](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/master/vignettes/locales.Rmd)

Comment: Thanks for your comments!@akrun @Kevin Arseneau I tried as what you said. But it still doesnot work. `Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
read_csv("a,b\n坏,好")
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "chinese")
read_csv("a,b\n坏,好")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because that the characters are marked as `UTF-8` whereas the actual encoding is the system default (you can get by `stringi::stri_enc_get()`).

So, you can do either:

1) Read data with the correct encoding:

```
df <- read_csv("中文,英文\n英文,德文", locale = locale(encoding = stringi::stri_enc_get()))
```

2) Read data with the incorrect encoding and mark them with the correct encoding later (note that this does not always work):

```
df <- read_csv("中文,英文\n英文,德文")
df <- dplyr::mutate_all(df, `Encoding<-`, value = "unknown")
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion! It works pretty well!