# Read non-english text as data frame using readr package (encoding issue)

Tags: r, encoding, readr

I have a text with data. The text is non-English with European-style numbers and tab-delimited values:

```
Ežeras  Plotas, ha  Gylis, m
Drūkšiai    4479,0  33,3
Dysnai  2439,4  6,0
```

I want to read it into R using functions from `readr` package, but I face an encoding issue in the resulting dataset.

The code:

```r
Sys.setlocale(locale = "Lithuanian")

library(readr)

read_tsv(locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","),
"Ežeras     Plotas, ha  Gylis, m
Drūkšiai    4479,0  33,3
Dysnai  2439,4  6,0
")
```

The result:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  `E\xfeeras`      `Plotas, ha` `Gylis, m`
  <chr>                   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 "Dr\xfbk\xf0iai"        4479        33.3
2 Dysnai                  2439.        6
```

I also tried `encoding = "native"` and `encoding = "unknown"` inside the function `locale()`, but these options are not recognized.

I can write the data into a text file and read that file as well as use `data.table::fread()`, but these are not the options I am searching for.

---

```r
devtools::session_info()

Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.456)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257   
 tz       Europe/Helsinki             
 date     2018-10-15                  

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version    date       source                          
 assertthat   0.2.0      2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
 base       * 3.5.1      2018-07-02 local                           
 cli          1.0.1      2018-09-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 compiler     3.5.1      2018-07-02 local                           
 crayon       1.3.4      2017-09-16 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
 datasets   * 3.5.1      2018-07-02 local                           
 devtools     1.13.6     2018-06-27 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 digest       0.6.18     2018-10-10 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 fansi        0.4.0      2018-10-05 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 graphics   * 3.5.1      2018-07-02 local                           
 grDevices  * 3.5.1      2018-07-02 local                           
 hms          0.4.2.9001 2018-07-25 Github (tidyverse/hms@979286f)  
 memoise      1.1.0      2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
 methods    * 3.5.1      2018-07-02 local                           
 pillar       1.3.0      2018-07-14 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 pkgconfig    2.0.2      2018-08-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 R6           2.3.0      2018-10-04 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 Rcpp         0.12.19    2018-10-01 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 readr      * 1.1.1      2017-05-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 rlang        0.2.2      2018-08-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 rstudioapi   0.8        2018-10-02 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                  
 stats      * 3.5.1      2018-07-02 local                           
 tibble       1.4.2      2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
 tools        3.5.1      2018-07-02 local                           
 utf8         1.1.4      2018-05-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                  
 utils      * 3.5.1      2018-07-02 local                           
 withr        2.1.2      2018-09-05 Github (jimhester/withr@8b9cee2)
 yaml         2.2.0      2018-07-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```

Comment: I tried on a Mac box with all US locales == "en_US.UTF-8" and get a result with none of those hex codes. See `?Sys.getlocale`, `?Quotes` and `?Encoding`. Perhaps this is Windoze with code page 1252?

Comment: I tried `Sys.setlocale(locale = "lt_LT.UTF-8")` on MacOS, which worked fine as well.  Please post the results of `sessionInfo()` ...

Comment: I added session information. And yes, I'm using Windows OS.

Comment: I believe this is related to bugs [15762](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15762) and [16232](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16232). Also see [Ista Zahn's article on character encoding hell in R for Windows](https://dss.iq.harvard.edu/blog/escaping-character-encoding-hell-r-windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`encoding = stringi::stri_enc_get()` should work. c.f.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999569/5397672

```
read_tsv(locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",",
                         encoding = stringi::stri_enc_get()),
         "Ežeras     Plotas, ha  Gylis, m
Drūkšiai    4479,0  33,3
Dysnai  2439,4  6,0
")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try fread from data.table library. It works with Lithuanian locale for me. Then you can convert to as_tibble() if like. 
Readr function converts output to UTF-8 by default. Thought after read_tsv you could use iconv() function. This solution also works fine.

Comment: Could you provide with an example of code, how you suggest using `read_tsv()` in combination with `iconv()` and the data I used in the question?

Comment: simplier solution:

xx <-"Ežeras     Plotas, ha  Gylis, m
Drūkšiai    4479,0  33,3
Dysnai  2439,4  6,0
"
x <- fread(xx) %>% as_tibble()
#-------------- or ------------
x <- read_tsv(locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","),xx)
Encoding(c(names(x),x[[1]])) 
Encoding(names(x)) <- "ISO8859-13"
Encoding(x[[1]]) <- "ISO8859-13"
x