# How to read utf8 csv with Chinese character in R?

Tags: r, csv

My system is win 10,with R 3.5.3 and Rstudio 1.1.463,`locale` as below:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

My classmate gave me a `UTF8` csv file `sample.csv` produced in linux system,[this file](https://ufile.io/kc279) can be produced by php script as below:

```
<?php
$a=
array (
      'col1' => 12,
      'col2' =>  'Y' ,
      'col3' =>  '<p style="text-align: center;">
    <strong style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">版权</span></strong></p>
<p>
    <span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">bla</span></p>
<p>
    <span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;"><img alt="" src="/functions/2.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 500px;" /></span></p>
<p>
    <span style="color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">bla</span></p>
' ,
      'col4' =>  '<br />
' );

 $fp = fopen("sample.csv", "wb");

$question_list_cols=array('col1','col2','col3','col4');

fputcsv($fp, $question_list_cols);
if (!fputcsv($fp, array_values($a))) {
        echo "fail<br />";
    }

fclose($fp);
?>
```

When I read `sample.csv` in R `df<-read.csv("sample.csv",header=TRUE)`, I got error `invalid input found on input connection`.
I tried  similar questions in SO, but no one is workable.

The problem  caused by Chinese characters `版权`. Everything is OK when I remove these Chinese Characters.

How to read utf8 csv with Chinese character in R?

Comment: Try `fileEncoding="latin1"` as a parameter in your `df<-read.csv()`.

Comment: @TomUdding,tried,got error`1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'sample.csv'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'sample.csv'`

Comment: Try to look here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996501/readrread-csv-issue-chinese-character-becomes-messy-codes) mainly the comments

Comment: @DJV,doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try `df<-read.csv("sample.csv",header=TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")` ?

Comment: @Theo,but this change Chinese characters to `<U+7248><U+6743>`

Comment: @Theo,I open `sample.csv` by sublime,confirm it's UTF8 format.but `df<-read.csv("sample.csv",header=TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8",encoding = "UTF-8")`will get error too.what's the problem of `fileEncoding = "UTF-8"`?

Comment: Have you saved your code in UTF-8 encoding aswell?

Comment: yes,confirmed format is UTF-8