# Reading Chinese characters in R

Tags: r

I am using read.xlsx to load a spreadsheet that has several columns containing Chinese characters.

```
slides<-read.xlsx("test1.xlsx",sheetName="Sheet1",encoding="UTF8",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I have tried with and without specifying encoding, I have tried reading from a text file, CSV file etc. No matter the approach, the result is always:

```
                  樊志强 ->  é‡åº†æ–°æ¡¥åŒ»é™¢
```

Is there any package/format/sys.locale setup that might help me get the right information into R?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955582/displaying-utf-8-encoded-chinese-characters-in-r?

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `readr` package, and use the following code:

```
library(readr)
loc <- locale(encoding = "UTF-8")
slides <-  read_table("filename", locale = loc)
```